# Estimating Predictive Uncertainty for unlabeled data

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning, prediction

I am trying to estimate the predictive uncertainty for a deep neural network. While I do have a labeled training set, I´m trying to measure uncertainty for some unlabeled production data.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01474) proposes the use of Deep Ensembles and Adversarial Training to compute a measurement of uncertainty. However, it uses Brier Score as a metric which requires me to know the real label of my production data.
Is there a similar way or metric which does not require labeled data?

Another approach was described by [Yarin Gal](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/blog_3d801aa532c1ce.html) utilizing Monte Carlo Dropout. However I can´t get any useful results using that technique on my model.

I want to use my model in an online learning task. As the given data may very over time, I need to detect examples where my model is highly uncertain, so I can manually classify those examples.

Answer (score 2):

[See Authors comment in the thread here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9412#issuecomment-366487249)

So by default the dropout is only used in training time. Then in test time the dropout probability is set to 0. But there is a easy way to enable it so that it stays 'on' even during the test time. 
    import keras

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(10,))
x = keras.layers.Dense(3)(inputs)
outputs = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x, training=True)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

By setting **`training=True`** it remains active in during test time. This can be called Monte Carlo dropout or more popularly dropout at inference time. I hope it helps.